# Always start with initial controller of the storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, startup

I want the app to always start at the initial controller of the storyboard.
The Initial controller is a standard uiviewcontroller.

Default behavior: I'm navigating through the app, and quit it at a specific view. When I restart the app, I want the user to start at a specific loading screen, not at the last visible controller.

I have already searched for this, but found nothing. Is this possible I think it should be, right?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to `YES` in your app's `Info.plist`.  Xcode's `Info.plist` editor will use the friendly name “Application does not run in background” for this key if you don't set the “Show Raw Keys/Values” option.

[image: exits on suspend entry in Info.plist]